# Weird output while processing images with Processing 3.3.7

Tags: java, image, processing

## What I have:

I have 2 images with same size (500), one is a normal image and the other have a message with only **black pixels** (message) and *white pixels* (nothing).

What i do in `encodeImage()` is create `messageEncoded` with pixels of `originalImage` and incrementing it by 1 if the pixel of the `messageImage` isn't white.

This is how i'm hidding a image in another image, so `decodeImage()` should read the `originalImage` and `messageEncoded` to extract the `messageImage`, creating `messageDecoded` with white pixel when doens't change the pixel and black and it changes.

```
PImage originalImage;      
PImage messageImage; 
PImage messageEncoded;
PImage messageDecoded;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);

  originalImage = loadImage("jap.jpg");  
  messageImage = loadImage("msg.jpg");  

  messageEncoded = createImage(originalImage.width, originalImage.height, RGB);
  messageDecoded = createImage(originalImage.width, originalImage.height, RGB);

  encodeImage();
}

void decodeImage() {

  originalImage.loadPixels();
  messageEncoded.loadPixels();
  messageDecoded.loadPixels();

  PImage msg = loadImage("messageEncoded.jpg");
  msg.loadPixels();

  for (int x = 0; x < originalImage.width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < originalImage.height; y++ ) {
      int loc = x + y * originalImage.width;

      if (messageEncoded.pixels[loc] == originalImage.pixels[loc]) {
        messageDecoded.pixels[loc] = color(255);
      } else {
        messageDecoded.pixels[loc] = color(0);
      }
    }   
  }

  messageDecoded.updatePixels();
  messageDecoded.save("messageDecoded.jpg");
  image(messageDecoded, 0, 0);

}

void encodeImage() {  
  originalImage.loadPixels();
  messageImage.loadPixels();
  messageEncoded.loadPixels();

  for (int x = 0; x < originalImage.width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < originalImage.height; y++ ) {
      int loc = x + y * originalImage.width;

      if (messageImage.pixels[loc] != color(255)) {
        float r = red(originalImage.pixels[loc]);
        float g = green(originalImage.pixels[loc]);
        float b = blue(originalImage.pixels[loc]);
        messageEncoded.pixels[loc] = color(r + 1, g + 1, b + 1);
      } else {
        messageEncoded.pixels[loc] = originalImage.pixels[loc];
      }

    }
  }

  messageEncoded.updatePixels();
  messageEncoded.save("messageEncoded.jpg");
  //image(messageEncoded, 0, 0);


  decodeImage();
}
```

## The Problems:

1. I have the variable `PImage msg` in `void decodeImage()` that I'm not using. This variable should be the same as the global `messageEncoded` because it's reading the file that it just outputed, but if I use `msg`, changing

   ```
       if (messageEncoded.pixels[loc] == originalImage.pixels[loc]) {
               messageDecoded.pixels[loc] = color(255);
             } else {
               messageDecoded.pixels[loc] = color(0);
             }
   ```

   into

   ```
       if (msg.pixels[loc] == originalImage.pixels[loc]) {
               messageDecoded.pixels[loc] = color(255);
             } else {
               messageDecoded.pixels[loc] = color(0);
             }
   ```

   the result is totally different and weird. Why? What is the difference between `messageEncoded` and `msg`?
2. `messageDecoded` is a little bit wrong, why it's having this wrong black dots?

   - I made the `messageImage` in paint, so i though paint is creating non-black dots, but i look all pixels, even put a single black pixel and still appeared some black dots around it.

---

- The `originalImage`. I found this on google by typing '500x500 images'. [image: originalImage]
- The `messageImage`. I created this on paint and save it with 500x500 dimentions (for testing it can be and draw with only black and with pixels).[image: messageImage]
- The very weird picture that happens when I use `msg`. (Problem 1)[image: msg]
- The `messageDecoded` the have black dots around it. Can I call it noise? (Problem 2)[image: messageDecoded]

## Edit 1:

The weird image and the problem 1 is solved when I use PNG images, but the 2 problem of the "noise" isn't fixed yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that JPEG encoding is causing the problem (the noise looks characteristic of compression artifacts). You'll need to work with images in a lossless format such as *.PNG* to alleviate the problem.

- Recreate `messageImage`, saving it as a *.PNG* this time.
- Convert `originalImage` to *.PNG* and modify your code such that
  Processing saves the images as *.PNG*.

It's ok to use a JPEG as the source image; the problem arises from successive JPEG saving/encoding (where more pixels than simply those which are being encoded are changed).

Comment: I tested using only PNG images and the weird image didn't appear, now `msg` and `messageEncoded` is the same, but the noise is still appearing in the final result.

Comment: @Vencovsky You are sure `messageImage` isn't a JPG and isn't a conversion from JPG to PNG?

Comment: nice, that solved the problem. The picture can't be a conversion of JPG to PNG